# Salesforce1, global action doesn't show up on Flexipage

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to add a custom global action to a Flexipage in Salesforce1, but I can't see any button showing up on the bottom of my Flexipage like the tutorial. I'm on API version 32.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>entityName</name>
                <value>MUSW__Inspection__c</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>filterName</name>
                <value>Mobile_Inspection_List</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>main</name>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Mobile Inspection List</masterLabel>
    <quickActionList>
        <quickActionListItems>
            <quickActionName>New_Inspection</quickActionName>
        </quickActionListItems>
        <quickActionListItems>
            <quickActionName>NewNote</quickActionName>
        </quickActionListItems>
    </quickActionList>
    <type>AppPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Any thought? All I see on my Flexipage is,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you marked the VisualForce page as "Available for Salesforce mobile apps".[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm working with Flexipage not Visualforce page.

Comment: No problem, I thought you are using a "custom" global action which is a Visual force page.